# How do I add the Lua module for nginx on Alpine linux?

Tags: docker, nginx, lua, alpine-linux

I'd like to have a lean Docker image for nginx with the Lua module enabled. How can I create this based on Alpine linux?

Answer (score 24):

Here is a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add --no-cache nginx-mod-http-lua

# Delete default config
RUN rm -r /etc/nginx/conf.d && rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Create folder for PID file
RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

# Add our nginx conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx"]
```

Installing the `nginx-mod-http-lua` package will also install `nginx` and `luajit`, among others.

The `nginx.conf` should contain at least this:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

pcre_jit on;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

daemon off;
```

Comment: These `load_module` are not needed if you don’t remove `include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;` from the default [nginx.conf](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blob/954391ce7493439d12180d5c5118dee26f8ac587/main/nginx/nginx.conf#L15).

Comment: @Marian: How do we install luarocks in this case? I did find include path for luajit.

Comment: load_module" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d

Comment: Why the --no-cache flag?

Comment: @jurl That's explained well in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119046/1228491

Comment: Lots of failures! Building from source code is Absolutely necessary！

Answer (score 7):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine
RUN  mkdir -p /run/nginx
RUN  apk add --no-cache nginx-mod-http-lua
COPY nginx_conf/ /etc/nginx/ # Your nginx conf
COPY lua/ /etc/lua/          # Your lua files
```

First line of nginx conf:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
pcre_jit on;
```

Comment: nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" version 1016001 instead of 1018000 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Comment: weird... that was not happening last year. Try with  FROM nginx:1.15-alpine 
I checked and is working. If you do the research to make it works with latest version please let me know the results. Anyways I edited the original answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: The Nginx version does not match the module version, It seems that `apk add` cannot specify a version number.

Comment: Current alpine version is 1.21 - is there another solution apart from going back several nginx versions?

Comment: You can use the tag `stable-alpine` (nginx version 1.20.2). But I have another error `module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" is not binary compatible `. Do you have any clue to resolve it?

Comment: @wolfgunner same error for me.

Answer (score 3):

We use Openresty, a platform that integrates nginx and Lua.

In the default nginx file, you could call Lua like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # 'ssl' parameter tells NGINX to decrypt the traffic

    # 1
    location ~ /api/(.*) {
        resolver xxx.x.x.xx;

    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        ngx.req.set_header("x-header", "12345678901234567")

    }
}
```

The alpine image here: https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/tree/master/

There is also an alpine-fat that had `make`, `git` and other libraries that can help you build within your Docker image.

Answer (score 3):

See: "Adding third-party modules to nginx official image"
At: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/modules

"It's possible to extend a mainline image with third-party modules either from your own instuctions following a simple filesystem layout/syntax using build_module.sh helper script, or failing back to package sources from pkg-oss."

```
$ docker build --build-arg ENABLED_MODULES="ndk lua" -t my-nginx-with-lua .
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Luc Chauvin's answer, here's a full walkthrough using the information from the [guide on GitHub](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/modules) as well as the changes necessary to get it working with docker compose. This guide assumes that you previously used the provided alpine nginx image with the service set up like:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
```

1. Download the base builder dockerfile: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/modules/Dockerfile.alpine (there is also a [debian based version available](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/modules/Dockerfile)).
2. Update the service in your `docker-compose.yaml` file to build the modules. Use the folder containing the dockerfile for the context, for this example I've placed it alongside the compose file:

   ```yaml
   services:
     nginx:
       build:
         context: ./
         args:
           ENABLED_MODULES: ndk lua
   ```
3. Add the following to the top of your `nginx.conf` to load the modules:

   ```
   load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
   load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
   ```
4. Build the container with `docker compose build`. This will take a while, but at the end you should be able to `docker compose up` without issue.

Answer (score -4):

You look on the Docker Hub

https://hub.docker.com/

and you find an Nginx image, based on Alpine Linux, with Lua support

Some examples

https://hub.docker.com/r/ilagnev/alpine-nginx-lua/

or

https://hub.docker.com/r/firesh/nginx-lua/

Have a look at the Dockerfile for more details

Comment: I found both of these, but found that none of the two was up to date (last pushed a year ago). In addition, they are lacking the information on how to enable the module.