# Nexus IQ flagged Component-Unknown for libraries in alpine openjdk

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, nexus-iq

When I try to scan docker image with nexus IQ, it flagged Component-Unknown for libraries in openjdk alpine.

```
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/cldrdata.jar
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/dnsns.jar
```

My docker file is as follows

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache openjdk8 dumb-init \
    && rm -rf \
         /usr/share/man/* \
         /usr/includes/* \
         /var/cache/apk/*
```

Is there other repo I should be getting from to get the proper libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the right package based on a file you know is missing on Alpine is pretty straightforward.

You just need to go to the page https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents and fill in the file name.
Here, filling in the file name `charsets.jar` [is pointing at the fact that you should install the package `openjdk8-jre-lib`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=charsets.jar&path=&name=&branch=v3.14).

Furthermore, mind that the `--no-cache` flag you are using is already doing [`update`, `upgrade` and the `rm` on `/var/cache/apk/*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119046/2123530).

So, a trimmed working *Dockerfile* would be

```sh
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN apk add --no-cache \
         dumb-init \
         openjdk8 \
         openjdk8-jre-lib \
    && rm -rf \
         /usr/includes/* \
         /usr/share/man/*
```

<sup>Also mind about the good practice ["sort multi-line arguments"](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments), applied here.</sup>