# How to disable SSL verification in alpine's apk?

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

Is there any way to disable SSL verification at installing some packages?

I found how to add my certificate in trusted certificates, but I'd rather do disable this checking.

I need it to avoid following error:

```
SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: What's the scenario here? Since you can get SSL certificates for free I don't think there're package repositories with self-signed certificates any more. Is it some local repository or something like that?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I use VPN with self signed cetificates

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**For Alpine 3.18 and onward**, the option `--no-check-certificate` was added to `apk add`, so, your best bet is to follow [@Chen A.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76809042/2123530).

---

**Before Alpine 3.18**, that introduced the flag `--no-check-certificate` in `apk add`; one way to achieve this was to use an http mirror of the packet repository rather than an https version of it, then you won't have any SSL verification.

So, you could, for example do:

```
apk add \
  --no-cache \
  --allow-untrusted \
  --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main \
  alpine-sdk
```

To find the right package repository for your version of Alpine, you have a look in the file */etc/apk/repositories*.

Here is, for example, the content of the file for the Alpine 3.15 image:

```
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community
```

Comment: It doesn't work so, because if we read description of the _allow-untrusted_ switch it says:
`--allow-untrusted     Install packages with untrusted signature or no signature`
It has no connection with SSL verification during package fetching

Comment: And the [issue](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/-/issues/10650) in Apline repo is still opened

Comment: Didn't work for me, because the `fetch` command gets redirected to https immediately.

Comment: That's a working solution for a virtualbox vm (reboot it) behind the intranet ca root, see also https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/4332#issuecomment-1968777639

Comment: The correct switch is `--no-check-certificate`, as indicated by the other answer by Chen A.

Comment: @Sigmatics back when I answered this in 2021 the flag did not exists. Thanks for pointing out I will add a warning there

Comment: @Sigmatics please also pay attention that `--no-check-certificate` wasn't back ported in all version of Alpine, so, for versions prior to 3.18, which added the flag, you are sadly still left with no other option than this ugly trick.

Answer (score 14):

There was an [issue raised](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/-/issues/10650) in the alpine project.
This was solved by adding a new flag, [`--no-check-certificate`](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/-/commit/8ad1884f1f42c6ba3d21832d57287028eedd6f03)

Just add the flag to your `update` and `add` commands, e.g

```bash
RUN apk update --no-check-certificate \
    && apk add --no-check-certificate bash curl
```

Comment: Ideally, in an Alpine image, one does not `apk update && apk add ...`, but we rather use the [`--no-cache` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49118579/2123530).