# How can we improve improve docker image size

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

Can any one help me understand how can we
`Try to optimize the Dockerfile by removing all unnecessary cache/files to reduce the image size.` and
`Removing unnecessary binaries/permissions to improve container security`

My docker file look like this

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is actually some ways to do that I guess:

- multi-stage build

```
# STAGE1
FROM alpine AS stage1
WORKDIR /bin
RUN wget https://link/of/some/binaries -O app1 \
    && chmod +x app1 
# Run additional commands if you want

# STAGE2
FROM alpine AS stage2
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN wget https://link/of/some/binaries -O app2 \
    && chmod +x app2 
# Run additional commands if you want

# FINAL STAGE (runtime)
FROM python:3.7-alpine as runtime
COPY --from=stage1  /bin/app1 /bin/app1
COPY --from=stage2 /usr/local/bin/app2 /bin/app2
...
```

this will actually allow you to simply get only the binaries you need that you downloaded on the previous stages.

> If you are using `apk add` and you don't know where things are getting installed you can try to test on an alpine image by running `which command`

- remove cache

```
... # Install some stuff...

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: Thanks Affes, to remove cache do I need to add this command at the end of my build file?

Comment: In my docker file is there any need of removing cache? as I am not installing `apt` or `apk`

Comment: Yes you have to specify it  at the end since you want to reduce image size, or you could simply run `apk add --no-cache ...`  on every installation you can find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118579/alpine-dockerfile-advantages-of-no-cache-vs-rm-var-cache-apk), don't forget to consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: you can also run this to remove tmp files `RUN  rm -rf /tmp/*`