# How do I reproduce the caching issue mentioned in the Docker docs, but for alpine?

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get), *apt-get update* and *apt-get install* should always be executed in the same RUN statement.

Is the same true for alpine?
I tried to reproduce the cache issue mentioned in the docs, but *apk add* seems to always fetch the latest package list, regardless of the *apk update*.

```
FROM alpine:edge
RUN apk update
RUN apk add <any package>
```

Note: I used alpine:edge because of the frequent deployments. My reasoning was, when the package version changes, the *apk add* command should fail, because its using the cached version that no longer exists in the package list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alpine Dockerfile advantages of --no-cache vs. rm /var/cache/apk/\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118579/alpine-dockerfile-advantages-of-no-cache-vs-rm-var-cache-apk)

Comment: No, not really. I already looked at that post. My question is: "What is the equivalent of RUN apt-get update && apt-get install <package> for alpine based images?" and "How do I reproduce the caching issue mentioned in the Docker docs, but for alpine?"

Comment: I was mistaken. I accidentally used a package that is only available in the testing repo. I still couldn't reproduce the caching issue.