How can I add Git from Alpine to Docker container?
I'm trying to build a Docker container that is connected to CI inside my repo so it should have git, gcc and other utility things. But when I try to build my container it fails on the third line with such error:
ERROR [build 2/9] RUN apk update &&     apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git

I tried to fetch it from alpine using this command:
docker run --rm -it --network host alpine apk --no-cache add git

and also got
  git (no such package):
    required by: world[git]

Here's my dockerfile
ARG DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX
FROM ${DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX}golang:1.21-alpine AS build
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git

# create temp dir for build app
RUN mkdir "app"
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

ARG ACCESS_USER
ARG ACCESS_TOKEN
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE=${CI_SERVER_HOST} GOSUMDB=off
RUN echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin ${ACCESS_USER}\npassword ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc

# download requirements && compile
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /bin/main ./cmd/main.go

COPY --from=build /bin/main /bin/main
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/main"]

What am I doing wrong?

One small mostly off topic remark already: apk update && apk add --no-cache git is useless. apk update refresh the cache in order for the apk add to pick the package correctly. But since you are using --no-cache, it become useless. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118579/alpine-dockerfile-advantages-of-no-cache-vs-rm-var-cache-apk

Also, I cannot reproduce your issue, docker run --rm -it --network host alpine apk --no-cache add git works like a charm. Could you be behind a proxy, possibly?

@β.εηοιτ.βε Oh, yeah, thanks, I was behind a proxy. But why it is impossible to run in behind the proxy?

Is the image in DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX really golang:1.21-alpine? I can confirm that with DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX empty, L3 runs without problems. What Docker version are you using and on what platform? Does updating Docker make any difference?

Well, I run docker build without this argument so yes it should be just golang:1.21-alpine. I use docker 24.0.6( 4.24.0) on macbook air m1

@Cross because apk will hit the proxy and end up nowhere, you'll need to set the environment variables http_proxy and/or https_proxy for this to work.

If your container doesn't need the proxy to operate, you can add the proxy for just the build time with docker build --build-arg http_proxy=...

So I have multiple proxies cuz I run it under vpn and tried to run this command like docker build -t tips --build-arg http_proxy='162.23.112.143/32, 121.23.38.154/32' .  But I gues that I'm doing something wrong

Sadly does not seems possible @Cross: https://github.com/moby/moby/discussions/45580 (FYI Moby is the underlaying set of components that makes Docker)

@β.εηοιτ.βε Oh, so that's why I need to turn off my vpn every time I build the containter :( ?

Could you use just one proxy for the build time?
